# Is BWT based aligner suitable for any types of alignment task?

Tags: sequence-alignment, bwa, bowtie2

Burrows wheeler transformation based aligner like BWA or bowtie seems a standard alignment tool used many area. I was just wondering if there is a kind of alignment task in which BWT algorithm is not suitable.

Answer (score 3):

BWT based algorithm is just a component of a full-pledge aligner. To that end, it is applicable to most alignment tasks. However, for long-read alignment and metagenomes, we don't often use BWT based algorithms as other methods are faster.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the algorithm itself but Heng Li wrote an article about the future of BWA when releasing minimap2. It gives helpful insights about the topic : [Heng Li's blog](https://lh3.github.io/2018/04/02/minimap2-and-the-future-of-bwa)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you know that neither bwa nor bowtie by itself is splice-aware?

Comment: This isn't a limitation of the BWT algorithm, e.g. tophat2 uses bowtie2